# Optimize element-wise product of two std::vector<std::complex<float>> allocated with fftw_malloc()

Tags: c++, vector, simd

In a numerical simulation I am developing, I have to carry out many 2D discrete fourier transforms, which I use `FFTW` for, and element-wise multiplication of arrays.

I am using the following container for my data:

```
std::vector<std::complex<float>, fftwAllocator<std::complex<float>>> data(LX*LY);
```

`LX` and `LY` are not necessarily equal. The `fftwAllocator` is a custom allocator that uses `fftw_malloc()` for memory alignment.

At the moment, my element-wise multiplication looks something like this:

```
Wave &operator*=(const Wave &m) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < LX * LY; i++)
        _data[i] *= m._data[i];

    return *this;
}
```

I know, that the compiler probably does a lot of magic, but given that my arrays are already aligned in a SIMD compatible manner by `fftw_malloc()`, I thought I might be able to use vector instructions here to speed things up even more.

Is there an easy way to introduce platform-independent vector instructions here? I'm actually surprised, that a simple multiplication of vectors is not somehow included in `FFTW`, since so many people use it to convolve signals...

Comment: I would just write the clearest code like you have now and let the optimizer do it's job. Then measure performance and see how that holds up to self-rolled optimizations.

Comment: C++ does not know about vectorization.  You'd need a library to make this portable.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: I know that is probably the easiest and so far I was too lazy to really measure performance. However, I wouldn't be able to judge whether it is `quick`, because I don't know how fast it would be with SIMD.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I know that I would need extra code or even libraries. I thought that for pre-aligned memory it would be not too much work to extend my simple loop here. However, if it turns out to be difficult, I'd rather go with Sombrero Chicken's advice. :)

Comment: Does your compiler not auto-vectorize this already?  It can help the compiler do a better job if you tell it that the arrays are always aligned, but I don't think there's portable syntax for that.  In GNU C, `foo = __builtin_assume_aligned(foo, 64);` is one way, but you can also typedef an `aligned_float` pointer which is sort of hacky.  Anyway, `gcc -O3` should autovectorize this just fine.

Comment: I am using `gcc -O3` or `-Ofast`, but are you sure that it uses vector instructions? I thought one would need to use something like `std::valarray` for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Cordes suggested in the comments to my question, `gcc` is able to vectorize certain instructions itself, which can be checked via the compile flag `-fopt-info-vec-all`.

It turns out, however, that `complex& operator*=(const T& other);` cannot be vectorized, so I had to replace the function from my question with the following:

```
Wave &operator*=(const Wave &m) {
    // the builtin product of std::complex is not
    // vectorized by gcc, so we're doing it manually
    // here.
    float tmp;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _lx * _ly; i++) {
        tmp = _data[i].real();
        _data[i].real(_data[i].real() * m._data[i].real() - _data[i].imag() * m._data[i].imag());
        _data[i].imag(tmp * m._data[i].imag() + _data[i].imag() * m._data[i].real());
    }

    return *this;
}
```

With that, `gcc -O3` successfully vectorizes the loop.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you had `complex`, not plain `float`.  If you want efficient SIMD, a data layout that stores real,imag pairs together is a problem.  Separate arrays are more efficient (google SoA vs. AoS), so the compiler doesn't have to shuffle within vectors to combine the real part an imaginary part of the same `data[i]` element.  Instead it can just do a vertical SIMD operation between two vectors of 4 real parts and 4 imaginary parts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I am using FFTW and I'm not sure if I can easily make complex DFTs work with SoA storage. (Just now, I found that FFTW supports split arrays with its `Guru` interface: http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Guru-Interface.html#Guru-Interface . I may have a look at it.)

Comment: Ok, one more little comment: I tried using the guru interface of FFTW3 with split arrays for real and imaginary part (actually, I had to cram everything into one array because for FFTW the relative memory location of real and imaginary part need to fixed) and observed no real improvement over the `std::complex` version. So I'll stick to that, because it makes the code much more readable.